# Creating a subfolder in directory based off of Username then inserting a CSV file in that subfolder created

Tags: php, csv, subdirectory, fputcsv

I have the php working for when a user registers his user name and password it takes the user name and his/her password and inserts it into the users.txt file.  I also got it to work to create a subfolder with that users name within the general users folder.  What i want it to do is to create a books.csv file and put that into the subfolder that was just created after the users name.

This is what i have so far that i have i tried but it does not work:

```
<?php 

// Identify the directory and file to use:
$dir = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/users/';
$file = $dir . 'users.txt';



if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { // Handle the form.

    $problem = FALSE; // No problems so far.

    // Check for each value...
    if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $problem = TRUE;
        print '<p class="error">Please enter a username!</p>';
    }   

    if (empty($_POST['password1'])) {
        $problem = TRUE;
        print '<p class="error">Please enter a password!</p>';
    }

    if ($_POST['password1'] != $_POST['password2']) {
        $problem = TRUE;
        print '<p class="error">Your password did not match your confirmed password!</p>';
    } 

    if (!$problem) { // If there weren't any problems...

        if (is_writable($file)) { // Open the file.

            // Create the data to be written:
            $subdir = $_POST['username']; // folder to be created after the user name 
            $data = $_POST['username'] . "\t" . sha1(trim($_POST['password1'])) . "\t" . $subdir . PHP_EOL; // data is users name encrypted password

            // Write the data:
            file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

            // Create the directory:

            mkdir ($dir . $subdir); // making a directory within a directory of folder name of user name 

            //EVERYTHING WORKS TILL HERE IS WHERE I GET STUCK

            $filename = 'books.csv';

            file_put_contents($dir . $subdir. $filename);


            // Print a message:
            print '<p>You are now registered!</p>';

        } else { // Couldn't write to the file.
            print '<p class="error">You could not be registered due to a system error.</p>';
        }

    } else { // Forgot a field.
        print '<p class="error">Please go back and try again!</p>'; 
    }

} else { // Display the form.




// Leave PHP and display the form:

    ?>
```

I've tried other ways of doing it and it would insert a .csv file into the regular users folder as username-books-.csv but for some reason i cannot get that books.csv to be created within the newly created username subfolder.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing to append a `/` to your path.

`$dir . $subdir` will be

`C:/xampp/htdocs/users/myusername`.

Add to that the `books.csv` like you did would result in

`C:/xampp/htdocs/users/myusernamebooks.csv`

Solution:

```
$filename = 'books.csv';
file_put_contents($dir . $subdir . PATH_SEPARATOR . $filename); // Append the directory separator aswell
```

Note that your post missed the 2nd parameter to `file_put_contents` - so I left it out in this answer aswell since I don't know what you're putting there. It's not optional though.

Comment: Ok see, this is what it was doing before because i tried this. There is the C:/xampp/htdocs/users/ this code creates a new folder so for example i register my name then this gets created: C:/xampp/htdocs/users/Proximus.  Thats what i want, but i want a .csv file called Books to be inserted within the Proximus named folder i created so i get C:/xampp/htdocs/users/Proximus/books.csv.  What its doing right now which is what your code does is   C:/xampp/htdocs/users/Proximusbooks.csv. creating a csv filed called Proximusbooks.csv within the users folder.

Comment: You didn't add the `PATH_SEPARATOR` part of my answer (which is actually the only part I added to your code).

Comment: I put in exactly this exactly:  $filename = 'books.csv';
file_put_contents($dir . $subdir . PATH_SEPARATOR . $filename);   And it created a file called Proximusbooks.csv in the user folder as opposed to inserting books.csv into the Proximus folder. :(